# Which is the best way to edit a row in a data table?

Tags: users, data-tables, popup, inline-edit, page-layout

I need to design a mockup that consists of a data table featuring crud operations. I want to know the best way to design this:

Using inline editing?
Using a pop-up?
Using another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a mental-model, Excel is what most users envision when it comes to working in a spreadsheet so I wouldn't stray too far from that.

One of the things that Excel does well is to provide the user with several options: they can edit directly in the cell and up at the top of the page where functions are written. In addition, the user has control over the size and the cell/row which is extremely helpful when the amount of content in the cell/row becomes complex.

That said, I would look closely at what the user might be actually editing. If the content is long or gets complex and would benefit from carriage returns, you should consider giving the user the power to resize cell/row. If resizing is out of scope, then a modal would be perfect for editing. The modal would give users a larger area to work without having to leave the page. Often times, users need to reference other data/information that's in other cells/rows while editing/adding data to a cell so for that reason I would advise against taking them a new page.

Comment: Thank u @Koumtti, i think that now i have a better idea of making the difference between them.